# tensorflow single channel to rgb gives rank 0

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am creating a multidimensional array.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = np.zeros((10, 4, 4, 1))

print(a.shape)

(10, 4, 4, 1)
```

I want to add rgb channels, so I am doing:

```
tf_a = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(a, name=None)
print(tf.rank(tf_a))

Tensor("Rank:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

and it gives me a tensor with rank 0 instead of 4.

Also, the shape:

```
print(tf.shape(tf_a))
```

gives : `Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(4,), dtype=int32)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tensorflow, **tf.rank(tf_a)** and  **tf.shape(tf_a)** return tensors. Threore, you are printing the shape and rank of those tensors and not the shape and the rank of **tf_a**.

Therefore, I have edited your code slightly to get the actual results.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = np.zeros((10, 4, 4, 1))

tf_a = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(a, name=None)

sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():

   print(tf.rank(tf_a).eval()) # rank 
   print(tf.shape(tf_a).eval()) #shape

 4            #rank
[10  4  4  3] #result
```

Hope this helps.